# Улучшение читаемости кода Python

Tags: python

Имеется код:

```
 try:
        result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
                channel=entity
            ))

    except TypeError:
        try:
            result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
                id=entity
            ))
        except TypeError:
            try:
                result = client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                    chat_id=entity
                ))
            except:
                print("Какая-то ошибка")
    except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
```

Как лучше сделать, чтобы исключения:

```
except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
```

относились бы ко все result, а не только к самому верхнему, без прямого копирования.

Т.е по сути ставится вопрос, как уменьшить дублирование строк:

```
try:
    result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
            channel=entity
        ))
    # print("Успешно")

except TypeError:
    try:
        result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
            id=entity
        ))
    except TypeError:
        try:
            result = client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                chat_id=entity
            ))
        except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
            print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
        except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
            print("Чата больше нет")
        except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
            print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
        except ValueError:
            print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
        except errors.FloodWaitError:
            print("Ожидание суток")
    except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
    print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
    print("Чата больше нет")
except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
    print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
except ValueError:
    print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
except errors.FloodWaitError:
    print("Ожидание суток")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял, что вы хотите.

Но, возможно, вам поможет тот факт, что можно сохранять исключение в переменную, а потом её обрабатывать. Благодаря этому можно создать функцию для обработки исключения, а потом применять её всюду, где нужно.

```
def handle_error(err):
    if err == errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    elif err == errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    elif err == errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    elif err == ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. "
              "Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    elif err == errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
    else:
        print("Неизвестная ошибка")


try:
    result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
        channel=entity
    ))
except TypeError:
    try:
        result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
            id=entity
        ))
    except TypeError:
        try:
            result = client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                chat_id=entity
            ))
        except Exception as err:
            handle_error(err)    # Здесь используем функцию
    except Exception as err:
        handle_error(err)  # И здесь

except Exception as err:
    handle_error(err)    # И здесь тоже
```

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно)

Comment: Рад был помочь )